# Writing authorizers for serverless framework in Ruby

Tags: ruby, lambda, serverless-framework

I'm attempting to write an authorizer to protect calls to a lambda using the serverless framework. I'm using Ruby.

Configuration:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: ruby2.5

  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
      - KMS:Decrypt
      Resource: ${self:custom.kmsSecrets.keyArn}

functions:
  authorize:
    handler: handler.authorize
  hello:
    handler: handler.protected
    events:
      - http:
          path: protected
          method: get
          authorizer: authorize
```

The authorizer:

```
def authorize(event:, context:)
  if is_authorized?
    {
      "policyDocument": {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
          {
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": [ context.invoked_function_arn ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
          }
        ]
      },
      "principalId": "seeker"
    }.to_json
  end
end
```

The authentication I'd like to implement is token based: the `is_authorized?` method would receive the token and then return a policy that would allow access to the `protected` lambda function.
I'm not entirely sure what goes in the `PrincipalId` argument - I have no `user.id`.

Right now it complains that: `seeker-dev-authorize is not authorized to perform: iam:CreatePolicy on resource: policy seeker-allowed` which leaves me quite confused: I can't create a policy... on the policy? And where should I set this permission? On `IAM` or `serverless.yml`? Because I've set the permissions to encode/decode keys in serverless, maybe I should do the same with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used custom authorizers before, but I put together a small hello world project to try this out and this is what I found.

The protected function and the authorizer function:

```
def authorize(event:, context:)
  {
    "principalId": "test",
    "policyDocument": {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Resource": event["methodArn"]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
end

def hello(event:, context:)
  { statusCode: 200, body: JSON.generate('This is a protected endpoint!') }
end
```

Note that I'm returning the hash and not a string with `to_json`, I got an error back from the authorizer when using `to_json`.

Also note that I'm using `event["methodArn"]` to get the protected lambda ARN, using `context.invoked_function_arn` also caused me an error.

Besides that, not including an Authorization header in the request, will return an "Unauthorized error":

```
curl -X GET https://endpoint/dev/hello -H 'Authorization: test'
```

Lastly, about the `principalId`:

> The principalId is a required property on your authorizer response. It represents the principal identifier for the caller. This may vary from application-to-application, but it could be a username, an email address, or a unique ID.

Source: https://www.alexdebrie.com/posts/lambda-custom-authorizers/